# Как сделать такую перегрузку Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Вот ссылка на playground typescript [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20a(item%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0Afunction%20a(key%3A%20number%2C%20value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0Afunction%20a(item%3F%3A%20string%2C%20key%3F%3A%20number%2C%20value%3F%3A%20string)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(item)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(key%20%26%26%20value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aa(%27aaa%27)%3B%0D%0Aa(12%2C%20%27ss%27)%3B)

Проблема в том, что одна из сигнатур перегрузки выдает ошибку:

> Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.

Код:

```
function a(item: string): void;
function a(key: number, value: string): void; // Ошибка в этой строке на букве 'a'
function a(item?: string, key?: number, value?: string): void {
    if (item) {
        console.log(item);
    } else if (key && value) {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: добавь код в сам вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В реализации указан тип (optional string), а в перегрузке просят (number), потому компилятор и считает, что перегрузка не соответствует реализации. Вариант с объединением типов и проверкой на них компилируется:

```
function a(item: string): void;
function a(key: number, value: string): void;
function a(item_or_key: string | number, value?: string): void {
    if (typeof item_or_key == 'string') {
        console.log('item: ' + item_or_key);
    } else if (typeof item_or_key == 'number' && value) {
        console.log('key: ' + item_or_key + ', value: ' + value);
    }
}

a('aaa');
a(12, 'ss');
```